# How to keep TCP server open for clients as long as the android app runs?

Tags: java, android, serversocket, tcpserver

I have created an android app that serves as a server using a serversocket TCP/IP connection, i have successfully connected the app(server) to the client(which is a laptop) and when i switch pages on my android app, the connection closes.

I need some help, i'm a beginner on android development.

Comment: Have you read: https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html

Comment: I think services are the right way to go here -- the user interface should be ephemeral, and able to restart itself from saved state when it is killed. The service takes care of the bits that don't need a user interface. If you really, really have to keep the user interface part of an app alive, then a dirty trick I've seen other developers use is to have the app post a persistent notification message. I think that's considered a bit naughty.

Comment: @MorrisonChang looking into it now, thanks..

Comment: @KevinBoone somehow i figured out that the connection stays as long as the app is not destroyed from the phone, my problem now is that i cannot past the array i made from that certain page to other pages..